# postgresql concurrent transactions

Tags: postgresql, concurrency, orm

I have a project that I'm working on that uses a background thread to insert data into the database from a different source. Now one of the problems that I have occasionally, once the user interacts with the database an error due to "could not serialize access due to concurrent update" is triggered.

Because my data source generates a lot of data my background thread is always busy keeping up and inserting the data and I've written the algorithm to basically "retry" whenever a row is locked, so I can live with the occasional error that occurs on the background thread.

The real problem is that my users basically interact with the database via a website that has ORM mapping in various layers and it seems that occasionally the user might be modifying the same record that is being worked on by the background thread.

Is there any recommendation of what I could do make my not be confronted with the serialization errors?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably your users have been presented with some data from the database, and based on what they saw have decided to change something.  If the data they looked at is obsolete, why would you expect that decision based on obsolete information to still stand?  In general, they need to look at the more-current data and decide if they still want to make the change.

If those decisions are "easy" to make, then why do you have humans making them in the first place?  And if they are hard to make, what choice is there but to have the people re-make them?  There may be particular answers to this, but I don't see any general answers, and you haven't given us any particular details to work with.

Comment: In my case, the users are editing something that is not related to the background task. Basically my users are finalizing a purchase order which modifies stock indirectly; while my background thread is synchronizing stock quantities from sales occurring at the point of sale terminals in a grocery market. 

On a single day, there's maybe a race condition that occurs like 1 or 2 times per day. So I wrote them off as incidental, no biggie if you can retry in 5 minutes. Now I've heard that it's happening more frequently. It could be that my background thread is backlogged.

Comment: In my scenario, I have control over what I do in the background thread and those can be fairly specialized queries taking advantage of atomic and transactional principles however when you do queries like "SKIP FOR LOCKED" type of things.

Your other queries need to be compatible, locking and keeping fields unlocked for example. However, ORM generated queries the don't always generated the best of the code and in this case likely just locks entire rows while the underlying operation (addition/substraction) could be performed atomically also.